# What is the correct usage of arriviste/parvenu?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, loanwords

In one of the episodes of the TV show *Rosemary & Thyme* the word *arriviste/parvenu* was used.

Context how it was used: Person A considers person B as an arriviste/parvenu.

- Person A is rich and has been growing orchids all his life.
- Person B recently starts growing orchids.

My question is, can the words *arriviste/parvenu* be used for making political accusations? In the following context, Politician A considers Politician B as an arriviste/parvenu.

- Politician A: very senior
- Politician B: new to politics

Comment: They certainly could be used in politics, but hardly in the way you suggest. Anyone accusing another of *arrivisme* or being a *parvenu* would come across in an especially high-handed and demeaning way.

Comment: He would be bending a double-barrel shotgun around and shooting himself in the face--with both barrels. One English speaking man insulting another English speaking man in French? Talking like a snob about a "newcomer" to politics? Good-bye votes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're guessing well at the origin of the words, because how you seem to be interpreting them is close to their original French meanings.

However, often loan-words are borrowed to serve a particular purpose only and so have a narrower meaning in English than the original form. (The inverse can sometimes happen too).

*Arriviste* and *Parvenu* both describe someone who is "new money"; wealthy but without the social knowledge that allows one to fit into the social class of those who've enjoyed a similar level of wealth all their lives.

Both terms are used from a class-conscious position where the terms are negative because such people "don't know their place", or at the very least are so lacking in "class" that they cause embarrassment.

*Arriviste* is perhaps a bit more aggressive in this than *parvenu*, but neither are nice things to call someone.

> Can the words arriviste/parvenu be used while making political accusations?

Yes, extending the word to figuratively cover the political sphere, but you would have to do so from a distance, and even then it would be fraught.

The terms are associated with a snobbish attitude, and so while a pundit **might** get away with it they might also just seem prejudiced and anti-democratic. A rival politician would be much less likely to get away with it, because opponents would be sure to seize on it much as when [the British Government Chief Whip was forced to resign after allegations that he called police officers "plebs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plebgate).

You couldn't get away with it in public, but you might in private among some like-minded friends, but really you'd only be likely to do so if you actually were a bit of a snob anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jon ...I just wanted to know ..I dont have the intention of using these words neither politically nor at the personal front.Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Oh. I wasn't suggesting that you necessarily were, and I apologise if it came across that way. The "you" there was the generic "you" used informally where you might formally use "one" ("…one would only be likely to do so if one actually…") rather than directed at you specifically.